# Issue with WCF Transport Security SSL

Tags: wcf, security, iis, ssl, https

I have a set of WCF Services on one server that is being called from my website on another server.  Without any security and just basicHttpBinding, this works just fine.  Now I want to completely secure the same setup using SSL Transport with a self-signed certificate.

First I tried to use IIS on the Services Server to create a self-signed certificate, but the issue is that it is always creating the cert with the subject in mixed case but the url is lower case.  Not sure if that will cause an issue, but I didn't succeed with it.

So I used makecert to (1) create a root cert that I then installed the *.cer file on the client server and service server into the Root CA stores and then (2) created another cert, using the root as the CA, that will be used for signing.  I copied this one *.pfx and installed into the Personal store of the LocalComputer for both servers again.

So, now on my Services server, I went into IIS and setup the binding for 443 using the client cert.  Then I selected my virtual directory and setup SSL requiring SSL and then selecting 'Required' for Client Certificates.

Now, if I just try to bring up the virtual directory in IE, using https and the full name as it shows in the cert, I get 403.7.  I can't seem to get passed this error.

If I try to hit this virtual directory from the website server, I get a plain 403.

If I change my IIS setup to 'Accept' client certs instead of 'Require', the I can browse to my services on both boxes.

Somethings missing...but can't seem to find it.

**Update:**
Ok, so I created a one-page website and locked it down Requiring the same cert and was able to install that cert into IE on a client and hit the website.  Finally, after installing the cert into IT, it allowed me to browse my Services virtual directory and even bring up the page on one of my services.

Question 1:  When installing the server cert, I installed the private key version on both Server and Client machine into the LocalMachine -> Personal location.  Is this correct or should I just install the public key into the client?  It seems to be working.

Still problem - when making a WCF call now I'm getting the following:

SecurityNegotiationException: Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'myserver.mydomain.com'.

Here's my server configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add scheme="https" binding="basicHttpBinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="SecureCertBinding">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"></transport>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="MyName.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="SecureBehavior">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureCertBinding" name="SecureAlertService" contract="MyName.IMyService"></endpoint>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="SecureBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceCredentials>
                    <serviceCertificate findValue="myserver.mydomain.com" storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
                </serviceCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Here's my client configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_SmallData" maxReceivedMessageSize="5000000">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="524288" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
              <security mode="Transport">
                  <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"></transport>
              </security>
          </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="SecureEndpoint">
                <clientCredentials>
                    <clientCertificate findValue="myserver.mydomain.com" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
                </clientCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://myserver.mydomain.com/Services/MyService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="SecureEndpoint"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_SmallData" contract="MyName.IMyService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService"/>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

How can I tell if the client is sending the certificate with the request?

Comment: It might be a setting in your config. Post the `<system.serviceModel>` section.

Comment: I actually changed the web.config to have it open http right now.  I can't even browse to my virtual directory without getting a 403.7 error.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!!  Finally.
I restarted the whole process, including creating new certs and all.  Once I got passed the part where IE couldn't even navigate to the Services Virtual Directory, I knew from that point I was mainly up against WCF.

I use a service account on my Services Server for the application pool that has proper authority to the database.  This way my connection strings are Windows Auth.

**Make sure this service account has Full Permissions to the Cert (Snap-in...Manage Private Keys).**

After doing this, I was still getting an error but I found an entry in my System Event Logs that stated an error occurred when trying to retrieve the private key from a cert.  This finally helped.

My website (aka...Services client) is still running the application pool with ApplicationPoolIdentity.  If this is the case:

**Make sure to give the group 'IIS_Usrs' Full Permissions to the Cert.**

Bingo...everything worked from this point forward...complete security.